# Editing input boxes with text already in them in p5.js

Tags: input, attributes, p5.js

I'm trying to make an intro for an app I'm creating using the p5 web editor that asks the user basic questions about their name, age, sleep schedule, and mood. There is one screen that allows the user to correct the data they've already inputted. I'm trying to have this data be presented as a series of inputs that the user can edit when they click on it. The problem is, the correct data appears in the boxes but it can't be edited.
Here's a copy of my code:

```js
var screen1;
var screen2;

function setup() 
{
  createCanvas(650, 500);
  background(165, 223, 209);
  enterName = createInput();
  nameButton = createButton('Enter');
  const name = enterName.value();
  correctName = createInput();
  declareBooleans();
}

function draw() 
{
  if (screen1 == true)
  {
    drawScreen1();
  }
  else if (screen2 == true)
  {
    drawScreen2();
  }
}

function drawScreen1()
{
  textSize(80);
  fill(255);
  text("What's Your \n    Name?", 120, 200);
  enterName.position(213, 350);
  enterName.size(170, 30);
  enterName.style('font-size', '21px');
  nameButton.position(enterName.x + enterName.width, 350);
  nameButton.size(70, 36);
  nameButton.style('font-size', '21px');
  nameButton.mousePressed(screen1MousePressed);
}

function drawScreen2()
{
  enterName.remove();
  nameButton.remove();
  background(165, 223, 209);
  const name = enterName.value();
  correctName.value(name);
  textSize(70);
  text("Is this correct?", 100, 80);
  textSize(30);
  text("(Type in the boxes to change your answers)", 35, 120);
  textSize(30);
  text("Name:", 20, 190);
  correctName.position(120, 150);
  correctName.size(150, 50);
  correctName.style('font-size', '26px');
}

function declareBooleans()
{
  screen1 = true;
  screen2 = false;
}

function screen1MousePressed()
{
    screen1 = false;
    screen2 = true;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.9.0/p5.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.9.0/addons/p5.dom.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that once the boolean `screen2` changes to `true` the second screen is being drawn every time the `draw()` function is executed, which is usually several times per second, so the input gets re-rendered with the default value before any changes can be seen.

A way to deal with it could be to use `noLoop()` to stop the re-drawing, like this:

```
function screen1MousePressed()
{
    screen1 = false;
    screen2 = true;
    noLoop();
}
```